# Relational Database

Tags: database, relational

Can you do more than one clause in SQL without using aggregation and only: selection, join?  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: Do you have a specific example in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean having multiple WHERE's (ands), then yes.

```
SELECT user.id, post.title
  FROM user LEFT JOIN post ON (post.user = user.id)
  WHERE (post.title LIKE '%Monkeys%')
    AND (user.id > 3)
    AND (user.id < 20)
```